# Category of UIAlertView need callback for alert button click iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

My scenario is as follows

1) I created a `Category` for `UIAlertView` class

```
//UIAlertView+Remove.m file
#import "UIAlertView+Remove.h"

@implementation UIAlertView (Remove)

- (void) hide {
    [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}

- (void)removeNotificationObserver
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSCalendarDayChangedNotification object:nil];
}

@end
```

2)Added a notification to UIAlertView object when its show

> 3)And I want to call `removeNotificationObserver` method when user
>   click on any button in alertview to remove notification observer.

**My tried out scinerios**,

- Calling its from `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` delegate is not possible here because of delegate is not properly set to all alertview objects.
- Called it from a `-dealloc` method in category but `-dealloc` is not triggering when alertview close

Can anybody help me to get through this?

Comment: FYI - `UIAlertView` has been deprecated for several years now. You should be using `UIAlertController`.

Comment: its around 4 years old project, so updating to alerviewcontroller is time-consuming. Anyway thank you for your advice can you please help me with this scenario.

Comment: `UIAlertController` (which replaced `UIAlertView`) is specifically designed to handle this kind of behaviour.  I think you'll find it easier to switch to `UIAlertController` than to try to hack this behaviour onto `UIAlertView`.  `UIAlertController` uses a separate code block to call for each alert action (button).  It's trivially simple to implement and keeps all the related code in the same place instead of splitting it across multiple methods.  See the example at:  https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller

Comment: I know `UIAlertController` will solve the issue But in my project, there are around 30+ `UIAlertView` objects and their `delegate` handlings codes(1000+ lines) are present. it's not affordable for me to change all code and go for a full testing process. Anyway +1 for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for the responses!

Finally, I solved it myself by implementing SubClass for `UIAlertView` instead of using `Category`. Here I commented my code snippet, it may be helpful for those who experience same issue

```
//UIAlertView_AutoClose.m file

#import "UIAlertView_AutoClose.h"

@implementation UIAlertView_AutoClose

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
            message:(NSString *)message
           delegate:(id)delegate
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
  otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    if(delegate == nil){
        delegate = self;
    }

    return [super initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles, nil];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSCalendarDayChangedNotification object:nil];
    NSLog(@"Reached alertview_autoclose");
}

- (void) hide {
    [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSCalendarDayChangedNotification object:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: Great but make sure from the next time convert old UIAlertview to UIAlertcontroll.

Answer (score 2):

> UIAlertView is deprecated since iOS8 so I suggest you should not use it anymore instead of that you can use UIAlertController as below which can perform the action of buttons without the use of any delegate methods.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
alertControllerWithTitle: @"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"OK" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler: ^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {  
                                   }];
[alertController addAction: OKAction];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"cancel" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler: ^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   { 
                                   }];
[alertController addAction: cancelAction];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I know `UIAlertController` will solve the issue But in my project, there are around 30+ `UIAlertView` objects and their `delegate` handlings codes(1000+ lines) are present. it's not affordable for me to change all code and go for a full testing process. Anyway +1 for your suggestion